# Count repeated values in variable and add results to a new one in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a SPSS dataset with information of different household members and I need to generate a new variable that counts the number of people that compose each one of these households.The original dataset is something like:

`ID  | age | height`

`332 | 23  | 1.78`

`332 | 27  | 1.65`

`344 | 56  | 1.79`

`344 | 34  | 1.98`

`344 | 15  | 1.58`

etc... and I need to generate a new variable that counts the id repetitions such as 'n' in:

`ID  | age | height | n`

`332 | 23  | 1.78   | 2`

`332 | 27  | 1.65   | 2`

`344 | 56  | 1.79   | 3`

`344 | 34  | 1.98   | 3`

`344 | 15  | 1.58   | 3`

Is there any straightforward way to do it with window commands or do I need to use command language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the [AGGREGATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_aggregate.htm) command.

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=ID /Count=N.
```

Comment: I had to take advice from [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in)!

Comment: Hence the gentle nudge. Welcome!